# Hyperledger fabric chaincode installation problem

Tags: installation, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca, chaincode

when i try to install the chaincode on my channel and peers this error message is showing again and again "Error: failed to endorse chaincode install: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = keepalive ping failed to receive ACK within timeout
Chaincode installation on peer0.org1 has failed
Deploying chaincode failed"
what should i do for cancel out this error.

I expect the channel id here.

Comment: You should probably provide some additional information, such as the Fabric version used, what CLI command or API calls you are using for the install, and any relevant information about the chaincode or Fabric network configuration.

Comment: i used fabric 2.5 .  cli command for installation the chaincode -"peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz" ans i am using the fabric-samples "asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript " chaincode.

Comment: Are you executing from inside the peer container of the outside? how did you set the CORE_PEER_XXXXX env vars? Provide more context.